# Gzip compression does not have correct response header

Tags: node.js, express, gzip

I'm trying to compress my html requests using `compression`

The files are not getting compressed. To confirm this I have looked at the size differences, headers, and a online tool.

I think the response headers are missing:

```
Context-Encoding: gzip
```

Image from my current headers: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pXsh.png

This is how to initialized the `compression`. I'm using nodejs, with express.

```
var express = require('express');
const compression = require('compression')


var app = express();

app.use(compression())

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
```

Comment: I don't see `Content-Type` in a response. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

The `compression` has an [optional](https://github.com/expressjs/compression#filter) `filter` option with a default behaviour. From the doc:

> The default filter function uses the [compressible](https://github.com/jshttp/compressible) module to determine if res.getHeader('Content-Type') is compressible.

So you should double check you router code against to be sure that you page render produce a valid content-type that can be compressed.